# Listview Custom Adapter getView number is limited

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

This is the output of my android monitor.Actually i have 21 items to add inside the listview, but it only come out 9 items. I does not set any limit to the arrayadapter number to it.

```
01-05 20:44:23.368 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 0 null
01-05 20:44:23.378 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 1 null
01-05 20:44:23.388 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 2 null
01-05 20:44:23.398 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 3 null
01-05 20:44:23.408 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 4 null
01-05 20:44:23.418 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 5 null
01-05 20:44:23.438 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 6 null
01-05 20:44:23.448 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 7 null
01-05 20:44:23.458 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 8 null
01-05 20:44:23.488 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 0 android.widget.LinearLayout{41bb18f8 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-432,72}
01-05 20:44:23.488 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 1 android.widget.LinearLayout{41bb5708 V.E..... ......ID 0,73-432,145}
01-05 20:44:23.488 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 2 android.widget.LinearLayout{41bb9318 V.E..... ......ID 0,146-432,218}
01-05 20:44:23.488 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 3 android.widget.LinearLayout{41bbcf28 V.E..... ......ID 0,219-432,291}
01-05 20:44:23.488 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 4 android.widget.LinearLayout{41bc0b38 V.E..... ......ID 0,292-432,364}
01-05 20:44:23.488 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 5 android.widget.LinearLayout{41bc4748 V.E..... ......ID 0,365-432,437}
01-05 20:44:23.488 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 6 android.widget.LinearLayout{41bc8358 V.E..... ......ID 0,438-432,510}
01-05 20:44:23.488 5969-5969/? I/System.out: getView 7 android.widget.LinearLayout{41bcbf68 V.E..... ......ID 0,511-432,583}
```

**MyCustomAdapter.java**
this is my custom adapter class

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<PackingItem> packingItems;
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
int count;

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                       ArrayList<PackingItem> countryList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.packingItems = countryList;
    this.packingItems.addAll(countryList);
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox name;
    public TextView number_text;
    public Button plus;
    public Button minus;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return packingItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);

    if (convertView == null) {
        //convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_info, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_info,parent,false);
        holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        holder.number_text= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number_text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.number_text.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        holder.plus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (count>=0) {
                    count++;
                }
                finalHolder.number_text.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            }
        });

        holder.minus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (count > 0) {
                    count--;

                } else {
                    if (count <= 0) {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    finalHolder.number_text.setText(" ");
                }
                finalHolder.number_text.setText(String.valueOf(count));

            }
        });

        holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                PackingItem packingItem = (PackingItem) cb.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                " is " + cb.isChecked() + " " + packingItem.getNumber(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                packingItem.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                packingItem.setNumber(finalHolder.number_text.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }






    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    PackingItem packingItem = packingItems.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(packingItem.getName());
    holder.name.setChecked(packingItem.isSelected());
    holder.name.setTag(packingItem);
    holder.number_text.setTag(packingItem);

    return convertView;

}
```

}

In my **ItemList** java class i dont have sit the limit also

```
public class ItemList extends AppCompatActivity {

MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

String[] shirtlist = {"Gloves", "Hat", "Jacket", "Shoes"};
String[] underwearlist = {"Bra", "Pants" ,"Bandana", "Belt", "Blouse", "Cap", "Coat"};
String[] weatherlist = {"umbrella", "Raincoat", "Sunglasses"};
String[] personallist = {"Glass / lenses", "Health insurance", "ID card", "Money / credit card",
        "Passport / Visa", "Personal medication", "Tickets"};
Boolean shirt;
Boolean underwear;
Boolean weather,personal;
ArrayList<PackingItem> packingItems = new ArrayList<PackingItem>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    shirt =getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("shirt");
    underwear =getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("underwear");
    weather =getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("weather");
    personal =getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("personal");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    displayListView();

    checkButtonClick();

}

private void checkButtonClick() {

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
            responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

            ArrayList<PackingItem> packingItems = dataAdapter.packingItems;
            for(int i=0;i<packingItems.size();i++){
                PackingItem packingItem = packingItems.get(i);
                if(packingItem.isSelected()){
                    responseText.append("\n" + packingItem.getName() + "  " + packingItem.getNumber());
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(ItemList.this,
                    responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}


private void displayListView() {
    if (shirt){
        for (int i = 0; i <shirtlist.length; i++){
            PackingItem packingItem = new PackingItem(shirtlist[i],false);
            packingItems.add(packingItem);
        }

    }

    if (personal){
        for (int i = 0; i <personallist.length; i++){
            PackingItem packingItem = new PackingItem(personallist[i],false);
            packingItems.add(packingItem);
        }

    }

    if (underwear){
        for (int i = 0; i <underwearlist.length; i++){
            PackingItem packingItem = new PackingItem(underwearlist[i],false);
            packingItems.add(packingItem);
        }
    }

    if (weather){
        for (int i = 0; i <weatherlist.length; i++){
            PackingItem packingItem = new PackingItem(weatherlist[i],false);
            packingItems.add(packingItem);
        }
    }

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.item_info, packingItems);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            PackingItem packingItem = (PackingItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Clicked on Row: " + packingItem.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

I just put the array to the array adapter list only. Thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation for custom list adapter aren't right
Here is an example of my custim adapter

```
public class ResultListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context context;
    UsersMain values;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public ResultListAdapter(Context context,UsersMain values){
        this.context=context;
        this.values=values;
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.getNearestUsers().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView==null){
            viewHolder= new ViewHolder();
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.match_list_item,parent,false);
            viewHolder.username=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userResquestTv);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.username.setText(values.getNearestUsers().get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView username;
    }
}
```

Follow this. Hope helps

Comment: still no work, i have follow your code to do, i have upload again my code

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing getCount() method . Override that method and return list.Size(). Hope it helps.

Comment: But i'm not using base adapter , can i use Override getCount()  ?

Comment: Yes you can override method if you are using studio , press alt+insert and select generate override methods and will see list of methods available.

Comment: I dont think so he need getCount() for ArrayAdapter. The only important thing is adapter's `packingItems` must be >0.

Comment: May i know why the first 9 value will become null?

Comment: write this.packingItems=countryList; in constructor and remove this.packingItems = new ArrayList<PackingItem>();
    this.packingItems.addAll(countryList);

Comment: @bharat   the packingItems is used for getter and setter... And i get null value in first nine vakues

Comment: I follow your idea... but still same... i think the problem maybe is getView function... because i get null values first after that just get value, i got 21 items but only show until 9, then the other item repeat